# "Webpack Var Injection" injects the wrong values

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-2

I see this in the console:

```
/* 469 */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */ (function(global, console) {

'use strict';

//core

var path = __webpack_require__(20);
var assert = __webpack_require__(5);
var fs = __webpack_require__(30);
var util = __webpack_require__(1);

//npm
var colors = __webpack_require__(9);

//project
var sumanUtils = __webpack_require__(13);
var constants = __webpack_require__(10);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var loaded;

module.exports = function loadSharedObjects(pathObj, projectRoot) {

  if (loaded) {
    return loaded;
  }

  if (global.sumanOpts.init) {
    return loaded = {};
  }
```

as you can see, it's wrapping my code, and injecting both global and console...however, I don't really want Webpack to inject these variables, because apparently Webpack is injecting the wrong values for these.

How can I get Webpack to use

```
__webpack_require__
```

to source global and console?

The exact problem is that `global.sumanOpts` is undefined, and so I get an error saying that it cannot read property "init" of undefined. And that's why I am fairly certain that Webpack is not injecting the right value for global.

Comment: You're not showing what values are passed to the injection function (it's an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)). Despite that, I don't think webpack is injecting the wrong values. It looks like you're using strict mode, do you use `global.sumanOpts = ...` or just `sumanOpts = ...` where you define the global? In strict mode the variables don't implicitly become globals.

Comment: ah yes, let me investigate which variables are actually injected given the IIFE.